# Use VueJS with sailsjs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sails.js

How do i use vuejs with sails js.  I want to list and create dynamic content using Vue. How do I create route for CRUD operations for objects like posts and comments ? How do i check authorization on every route that the user must be logged in for this route to work. One more thing , how can I test the crud operations using Postman 
Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend that you invest the $9 and the time to go through the sails fullstack course. The course is linked to from the docs [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/full-stack-java-script-with-sails). It takes you from npm i sails, to pushing to production on Heroku, including payments, user management and a lot more. Taught by Mick McNeil, the creator of Sails.

Answer (score 4):

You have two ways of using VueJs in Sails.

- The view layer of sails js is built on Vue.js, so you can use the native implementation of Vue.js as described in sails js doc.
- Or, you can setup a Vue.js standalone app, and make it dial with you sails.js  backend by the way of http requests that can you send with http, axios, ... packages .

In both cases, you're gonna use the entry points that you will define in your `routes.js` file of `sails > config` folder which would corresponds to controllers that contains your CRUD requests. That is also the way you have to test your "CRUD" operations with postman, by requesting your entry points.

For authorization, a good practice would be to use the `policies` of Sails.js :)